# .htaccess how to redirect subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make subdomain redirect with "www", but this did not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(blog\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? ht-tp://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did it work? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope that helped!